# CDI and User Defined Functions (UDF) in Teiid / Wildfly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, cdi, user-defined-functions, teiid

Recently I began working with Teiid and Wildfly. I have a user defined function (UDF) that adds custom functionality to Teiid, and it works as expected. However, I need to modify it further and would like to use CDI to inject a bean from the Wildfly app server. I know that the UDF isn't managed by the container (it is a Wildfly module with an associated module.xml file deployed as a jar), so I've added (what seemed to be) necessary dependencies to module.xml but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to use CDI in a UDF with Teiid / Wildfly, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. although Teiid is a resident of WildFly it is using the infrastructure of WildFly for a variety of features like transactions, security, data sources, administration etc. It is not part of JEE or anything, so there is no direct way to do this. If you want to explain what you are trying to accomplish, maybe we can offer any further guidance on alternatives.